# Pull down to refresh

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, pull-to-refresh

I would like to implement a "Pull down to refresh" into my application. Just like twitter has in their iPhone app.

[image]

I have found a good source code: [PullDownToRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) but people are saying that they have copyrighted it or somewhat? Please could anyone clarify?

And also, does anyone know of any good tutorials for this pull down to refresh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orignal developer of Tweetie, Loren Brichter, has a [patent](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PG01&p=1&S1=20100199180.PGNR.&OS=dn/20100199180&RS=DN/20100199180) on the Pull To Refresh method, but said not to enforce eny fees.

I've not worked with any of the libraries out there, i've always rolled my own version, its not that difficult.

Comment: So it will violate the copyright if I try to incorporate the above into my app?

Comment: No, Loren Brichter has the patent for the pull to refresh, but will not enforce you to get a licence. That is what he said, if you want to be sure, contact him and ask for a licence.

Comment: Loren Brichter said that he "will not enforce you to get a licence." Where did he say that and don't Twitter own the patent now since they bought Atebits?

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/lorenb/status/21684045608 here a response if Loren will prohibit other developers from using the pull to refresh. can't find the one where he is asked if you will need a licence.

Answer (score 1):

I just got encountered with the same code. Have a look.
It does the same as twitter refresh functionality. Exactly the same. Try it. Works like a charm.

[here it goes](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

Answer (score 0):

A `Pull down to refresh...` was also made by Facebook team for their `Three20` project. You can download it [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/three20). You can use this library without any copyright issues.

Answer (score -5):

Use this code in view controller

```
  - (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
        NSLog(@"Creating Table Delegate for Auto Refresh");
        return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
    }
```